# JavaFX 2 and 3D

Tags: 3d, javafx-2

I read that Java FX has hardware accelerated 3D support. My Graphics card is Intel 945G with  DirectX Acceleration, DirectDraw acceleration, AGP Texture acceleration and Open GL capabilities.

But still.. `System.out.println(Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D));` gives me false.
Also X axis and Y Axis rotation does not work.

Is there any way to make it work? What about a software based solution?

Comment: Software based solutions works, when hardware based cannot work - in commmon case. Or you say about software 3d? What do you mean by X, Y rotation?

Comment: @AlexanderKirov I meant RotateTransition in Java FX. In which Z Axis rotation is plain 2D rotation. But Y Axis and Z Axis are 3D Rotations.

Comment: Try running this [rotation transform example](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1475424), which includes x, y and z axis rotations and see if it works for you.

Comment: Hi @jewelsea, I can't see anything besides a red 'cross' positioned inside the center of a dashed square, which moves in X,Y directions when I adjust the sliders, and the Z slider is not working at all.. Also there is no change when I press the buttons :(

Comment: So, you run 3d on machine, which doesn't support hardware rendering, so that JFX cannot launch hardware support? It seemed for me, that 3d in software mode is not supported...